# Is it a good idea to warm up a cache in the BEGIN block in Perl?

Tags: perl, caching

Is it a good idea to warm up cache in the BEGIN block, when it gets used?

Comment: It's best to preheat your cache at a minimum temperature of 200 degrees F (about 90 degrees C), before using it at full temperature.  Without pre-heating, the cache might develop small micro-fractures that could cause bit rot. :->

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't really provide any information on what kind of environment you're talking about, which I think is important. In most cases the answer is probably "no", but I can think of one case where it's a definite yes, which is preforking servers -- web applications and the like. In that case, any work that you can do "before the fork" not only saves the cost of having the children recompute the same values individually, it alo saves memory, since the pages containing the results can be shared across all of the child processes by the OS's COW mechanism.

If you're talking about a module you're writing and not an application, then I'd say no, don't lift things to compilation time without the user's permission unless they're things that have to be done for the module to work. Instead, provide a `preheat_cache` class method, and if your caller has a reason to need a hot cache at compile time they can put the call into a `BEGIN` block themselves. You could also use a `:preheat_cache` import tag but that's unnecessarily fancy in my book.

Answer (score 5):

If it's a choice between preloading your cache at compile time, or preloading your cache as the first thing you do at run time, there's virtually no difference.

If your cache is large enough that loading it will trigger a lot of page swaps, that's an argument for waiting until run time. That way, all your module loading and other compile time code can be done while your system is under a lighter load.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go with "no", even though I could be wrong.  Reasoning goes like this:  keep the code, and data it uses, small, so that it takes up *less* space in any caches (I am presuming you mean CPU cache, not programmatic hashes with common query results or some such thing).

Unless you see some sort of bad access pattern, trying to second guess what needs to be prefetched is probably useless at best.  In fact such code or initialization data is likely to displace something you (or another process on the system) were actually using.  Think about what you can do in the actual work part of the code to maximize locality of reference, to try to stay within smaller memory regions at any one time.

I used to use "top" to detect when processes were swapping between memory and disk.  I don't know of any good tools yet to tell how often a process is getting cache misses and going to plain old slow mo'board memory.  There must be such tools, I just don't know what they are yet (software tools, rather than some custom In Circuit Emulator type hardware).  Perhaps some thought on this earlier in the day...

Comment: This is tagged `perl`; the user is waaay to abstracted from hardware to even be aware of the existence of a CPU cache.

Answer (score 1):

by warm up I assume you mean use BEGIN() to guarantee the cache is preloaded before anything else in your script executes?

If you need the cache for your program to run properly, then yes, I think it would be a good idea.

Comment: wouldn't need it to run properly, but it would be a speedup, i was wondering if theres a downside to this

Comment: only downside I see is slower startup if you have a large cache.